# iOS CoreData image problems when working from a backup

Tags: ios, core-data

We have an app that allows users to create their own content, it includes "groups" of text and images which are then used in a game. They are written to the db, but also "restored" back to documents when they are "synced" or "backed up" to an existing or "clean" device.

A user is able to backup (.fgz) to a dropbox, which is meant to make it easy to share the game data between a number of devices. This works without any problems. The game content (db driven) and images can be shared to any number of devices without any problems.

Every time we update the App, we have a problem where the text entries are retrieved and are completely viewable (both from the local file system / sqlite) but for some reason the images in the same location will not display as they have previously (the path to the image seems to be deprecated during the update). This includes doing a "backup" to a newer version of the app, to a device which has not previously had the application installed, which is also really strange.

During testing, using Xcode and local copies (replicating "install in place", we can not replicate this problem using the exact same code, and databases. There are no errors or warnings. Is this a core data problem? Any other suggestions about what we might be doing wrong?

What is going on here? We are at our ends trying to find a solution. Is there a better way to do this? We have thought about keeping our files as part of the local file system only, but if we do this, they won't be as "shareable" via the dropbox.

Any thoughts about managing image data in iOS would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How are you creating and storing your paths to the images?